# Woo commerce custom email function for custom order status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need any idea or suggestion to develop email functionality in woocommerce plugin.

Requirement:

1. Need to create custom order status for orders
2. Activate custom email function for custom order status

Please suggest any idea for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

please check this link for point (1) create custom order http://www.sellwithwp.com/woocommerce-custom-order-status-2/

And for (2) point you had to create new functionality to above link where custom order status created.